# JSON create template file with $[Name] of the JProperty if it only exists once and $[DistinctParentname+Name] if the name exists multiple times

Tags: json, vb.net

for creating template XML and JSON I wrote a tool to automate the process.
For XML it was easy but for JSON i struggle to find a working solution.

Thats a part from a example file i get

```
{
    "receiver": {
        "address": {
            "receivername": "testreceiver",
            "companyName": "Test-Receiver1",
            "addressId": 1234,
            "addressLine1": "Test address 1",
            "addressLine2": "Test address 1.2"
        }
    },
    "delivery": {
        "address": {
            "deliveryname": "testdelivery",
            "companyName": "Test-Delivery1",
            "addressId": 4321,
            "addressLine1": "Test address delivery 1",
            "addressLine2": "Test address delivery 1.2",
            "addressLine3": null
        }
    }
}
```

I want the tool to make it like this

```
    {
    "receiver": {
        "address": {
            "receivername": "$[receivername]",
            "companyName": "$[receivercompanyName]",
            "addressId": $[receiveraddressId],
            "addressLine1": "$[receiveraddressLine1]",
            "addressLine2": "$[receiveraddressLine2]"
        }
    },
    "delivery": {
        "address": {
            "deliveryname": "$[deliveryname]",
            "companyName": "$[receivercompanyName]",
            "addressId": $[receiveraddressId],
            "addressLine1": "$[receiveraddressLine1]",
            "addressLine2": "$[receiveraddressLine2]",
            "addressLine3": "$[receivercaddressLine3]"
        }
    }
}
```

i tried iterating through every line using regex to replace the value but then i have no way to get the deviating parent node of the specific line. When using something like the following i can get the parent name but struggle to create the JSON syntax tree in the output text.

```
        Dim j As JObject = JObject.Parse(Input)
        For Each item As JProperty In j.Properties
            Dim itemObjects As JToken = item.Value
            For Each i As JObject In itemObjects
                For Each p In i
                    Debug.Print(p.Key.ToString & " = " & p.Value.ToString)
                Next
            Next
        Next
```

Iam currently out of ideas and don´t want to go through multiple 200+ lines JSONS and do this manually.

Would appreciate a bit of help.

Comment: Why not just a simple deserialisation to a typed object, update the properties on that object, then serialise it again to get the desired JSON output?

Comment: I tried that in the for each p in i. but p.value is readonly